# Increase the distance of a tikz path edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-styles

So, I made a graph in Latex, but I can't get the edges of the nodes to elongate themselves in any way. The weights of the edges are hard to read as they currently are. How can I fix this? Below is what I currently have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (1) at (0,0) {1};
    \node (8) at (0,-1) {8};
    \node (5) at (1,-2) {5};
    \node (2) at (-1,-2) {2};
    \node (3) at (2,-3) {3};
    \node (4) at (0,-3) {4} ;
    \node (7) at (-1,-4) {7};
    \node (6) at (-2,-5) {6};
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
          every node/.style={fill=white, circle},
          every edge/.style={draw=black ,thick}]
    \path [->] (1) edge node {$120$} (8);
    \path [->] (8) edge node {$170$} (5);
    \path [->] (8) edge node {$155$} (2);
    \path [->] (5) edge node {$115$} (3);
    \path [->] (5) edge node {$160$} (4);
    \path [->] (4) edge node {$160$} (7);
    \path [->] (7) edge node {$175$} (6);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess I could always mess with the coordinates, but I would much rather be able to scale the length of the edges.

Comment: Welcome! The thing is that you've specified absolute positions for the various points. You could add `scale=2` or something to the options for the picture. But this isn't the best way to draw something like this from scratch, so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've hard-coded absolute positions for the nodes. This isn't a good way to go about drawing this kind of diagram. However, if you just want a quick fix, you can pass `scale=<factor>` to the picture. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw},scale=3]
    \node (1) at (0,0) {1};
    \node (8) at (0,-1) {8};
    \node (5) at (1,-2) {5};
    \node (2) at (-1,-2) {2};
    \node (3) at (2,-3) {3};
    \node (4) at (0,-3) {4} ;
    \node (7) at (-1,-4) {7};
    \node (6) at (-2,-5) {6};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
          every node/.style={fill=white, circle},
          every edge/.style={draw=black ,thick}]
    \path [->] (1) edge node {$120$} (8);
    \path [->] (8) edge node {$170$} (5);
    \path [->] (8) edge node {$155$} (2);
    \path [->] (5) edge node {$115$} (3);
    \path [->] (5) edge node {$160$} (4);
    \path [->] (4) edge node {$160$} (7);
    \path [->] (7) edge node {$175$} (6);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: scaled graph]

What I would actually probably do is to use Forest and write something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={%
    circle,
    thick,
    draw,
    edge={thick,-{Stealth[]}},
    calign=fixed edge angles,
    l sep+=40pt
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    for tree={%
      edge label/.wrap value={node [fill=white, circle, midway] {$#1$}}
    }
  }
  [1
    [8, edge label=120
      [2, edge label=155]
      [5, edge label=170
        [4, edge label=160
          [7, edge label=160
            [6, edge label=175]
            [, phantom]
          ]
          [, phantom]
        ]
        [3, edge label=145]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The huge advantage here lies in a concise tree specification using bracket syntax and greater flexibility and ability to automate the format and content of the tree.

[image: Forest tree]